# Get admin groups with powershell

Tags: powershell

I work as system administrator in a company with 300 users.
I am looking for a PowerShell script to get all the groups, users in each group and additional single users located at the local admin group of multiple servers joined to a single domain.

This is what I have but it's for local users only.

```
# Get local and Groups Users List with Content

function get-localusers {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,valuefrompipeline=$true)]
    [string]$strComputer)
    begin {}
    Process {
      $Select = "Name","Class" | %{  
      Invoke-Expression "@{n='$_';e={ `$_.GetType().InvokeMember('$_', 'GetProperty', `$Null, `$_, `$Null) }}"  
       }
        If (Test-Connection $strComputer -Count 2 -Quiet){
         $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
         $Users = $computer.psbase.children | ? {$_.psbase.SchemaClassName -eq "User"}
                foreach ($User in $Users) {
                  $User | Select @{N="ComputerName";E={$strComputer}},@{N="User";E={$_.Name}},Class
                }
        }
      Else {
          "" | Select @{N="ComputerName";E={$strComputer}},@{N="User";E={"Not able to Ping"}},Class
        }
      }
end {}
}
Get-Content "c:\temp\Servers.txt" | get-localusers | Select ComputerName,User | Export-Csv "c:\temp\Local-User_$((get-date).toString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv" -NTI
```

This is the output from the script above.
"ComputerName", "User"
"mbptl-ws01","mbadmin"
"mbptl-ws01","Guest"
"mbptl-ws01","sv-dtb-pr"

Please help aggregating by groups ( that show users)

Comment: "*We don't use AD Poweshell module in our company.*" - then .. start using it?

Comment: Why is it that your organization cannot use the Microsoft provided tools?

Comment: What does AD have to do with local groups? Does this question have anything to do with AD? You are just asking about _local_ groups yes? What is your expected output? Can you show a sample? Is there anything you tried since it just appears you pasted code and what us to do all the work? We want to help but effort goes a long way and we need to know more about the end goal to be sure.

Comment: I removed references to AD as I don't see how it is pertinent to your question as I understand it. Please roll back if I am incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Matt
Since our AD is managed by another team, our security policy is very strict and won't allow me to use AD Powershell Module.
Why AD, as I'll get the AD group from the local Administrators group,
I'd like to query the active directory for member included in that group

regarding input <ComputerName>
Output:
AdminGroup_1 ( User1, User2 )
AdminGroup_2 ( User3, User4 )
User5
User6

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a good start :
https://4sysops.com/archives/create-a-list-of-local-administrators-with-powershell/

looks that this will at least get you the members for several computers

Comment: Thanks a lot  - I'll try that